# Looking for a cleaner more efficient way

Tags: lua

```
function GetDamage(spell, unit)
    if spell == _Q and (isReady(_Q) or qActive) and not HasItem(3025) and not HasItem(3100) and not HasItem(3057) and not HasItem(3078) then
        return myHero:CalcDamage(unit, ((((myHero:GetSpellData(_Q).level * 20) + 10) + myHero.totalDamage) + qStacks))
    elseif spell == _Q and (isReady(_Q) or qActive) and (HasItem(3057) or sheenActive) then
        return myHero:CalcDamage(unit, myHero.damage) + myHero:CalcDamage(unit, ((((myHero:GetSpellData(_Q).level * 20) + 10) + myHero.totalDamage) + qStacks))
    elseif spell == _Q and (isReady(_Q) or qActive) and (HasItem(3025) or fActive) then
        return myHero:CalcDamage(unit, myHero.damage) + myHero:CalcDamage(unit, ((((myHero:GetSpellData(_Q).level * 20) + 10) + myHero.totalDamage) + qStacks))
    elseif spell == _Q and (isReady(_Q) or qActive) and (HasItem(3100) or lActive) then
        return myHero:CalcMagicDamage(unit, ((myHero.damage * 0.75) + (myHero.ap * 0.5))) + myHero:CalcDamage(unit, ((((myHero:GetSpellData(_Q).level * 20) + 10) + myHero.totalDamage) + qStacks))
    elseif spell == _Q and (isReady(_Q) or qActive) and (HasItem(3078) or tActive) then
        return myHero:CalcDamage(unit, (myHero.damage * 2)) + myHero:CalcDamage(unit, ((((myHero:GetSpellData(_Q).level * 20) + 10) + myHero.totalDamage) + qStacks))
    elseif spell == _E and isReady(_E) then
        return myHero:CalcMagicDamage(unit, (((myHero:GetSpellData(_E).level * 40) + 15) + (myHero.ap * 0.6)))
    else 
        return 0
    end
end
```

this is my code to return x spell damage to x enemy, however while it works as intended it seems inefficient and ugly also I would like it to work a little differently and I'm not sure how to code it as such.

What I would like it to do is if I do for example `GetDamage(all)` or something similiar I would like it to return total damage I can do given `isReady(spell)` returns true ie if spell `q` and `e` are ready it would return the total of `q` and `e` only or if all were ready then would return all, additionally if I only need to know r's damage I could still just do `GetDamage(_R)`.

Is there a cleaner way to do this using a table or some more efficient manner to get the results I need? Because currently using `GetDamage(spell) + GetDamage(spell2) + GetDamage(spell3)` etc looks like very bad coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce new spell "ALL"

```
function GetDamage(spell, unit)
   local result = 0
   if (spell == "ALL" or spell == _Q) and (isReady(_Q) or qActive) then
      local bonus = 0
      if (HasItem(3057) or sheenActive) then
         bonus = myHero:CalcDamage(unit, myHero.damage)
      elseif (HasItem(3025) or fActive) then
         bonus = myHero:CalcDamage(unit, myHero.damage)
      elseif (HasItem(3100) or lActive) then
         bonus = myHero:CalcMagicDamage(unit, ((myHero.damage * 0.75) + (myHero.ap * 0.5)))
      elseif (HasItem(3078) or tActive) then
         bonus = myHero:CalcDamage(unit, (myHero.damage * 2))
      end
      result = result + bonus + myHero:CalcDamage(unit, ((((myHero:GetSpellData(_Q).level * 20) + 10) + myHero.totalDamage) + qStacks))
   end
   if (spell == "ALL" or spell == _E) and isReady(_E) then
      result = result + myHero:CalcMagicDamage(unit, (((myHero:GetSpellData(_E).level * 40) + 15) + (myHero.ap * 0.6)))
   end
   return result
end
```

Usage examples:

```
dmg = GetDamage("ALL", unit)
dmg = GetDamage(_Q, unit)
dmg = GetDamage(_E, unit)
```

---

**EDIT:**
There is another way of implementing the same by using a table with spells as keys and functions as values:

```
spell_dmg_func = {
   [_Q] = 
      function(unit) 
         if (isReady(_Q) or qActive) then
            local bonus = 0
            if (HasItem(3057) or sheenActive) then
               bonus = myHero:CalcDamage(unit, myHero.damage)
            elseif (HasItem(3025) or fActive) then
               bonus = myHero:CalcDamage(unit, myHero.damage)
            elseif (HasItem(3100) or lActive) then
               bonus = myHero:CalcMagicDamage(unit, ((myHero.damage * 0.75) + (myHero.ap * 0.5)))
            elseif (HasItem(3078) or tActive) then
               bonus = myHero:CalcDamage(unit, (myHero.damage * 2))
            end
            return bonus + myHero:CalcDamage(unit, ((((myHero:GetSpellData(_Q).level * 20) + 10) + myHero.totalDamage) + qStacks))
         end
      end, 
   [_E] = 
      function(unit) 
         if isReady(_E) then
            return myHero:CalcMagicDamage(unit, (((myHero:GetSpellData(_E).level * 40) + 15) + (myHero.ap * 0.6)))
         end
      end,
}

function GetDamage(spell, unit)
   if spells == "ALL" then
      local sum = 0
      for spell, func in pairs(spell_dmg_func) do
         sum = sum + (func(unit) or 0)
      end
      return sum
   else
      return spell_dmg_func[spell](unit) or 0
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you but is this the most efficient way to code this function or do you think there is a cleaner way?

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what I was looking for thank you